# Ожидание завершения функции

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Доброго времени суток.

```
    void FunctionZ()
    {
        (new Thread(delegate()
        {
          Console.Writeln(0);

            FunctionA();

          Console.Writeln(2);

        })).Start();
    }

    void FunctionA()
    {
        (new Thread(delegate()
        {

          Console.Writeln(1);

        })).Start();
    }
```

Проблема заключается в том что, при выполнении FunctionZ, не ожидается конец выполнения функции FunctionA, и код просто идет дальше. А нужно сначала дождаться конца выполнения функции FunctionA и только затем продолжить выполнение.

UPD:

Немного конкретизирую, при выполнении кода сверху зачастую выводится 0 2 1. Хотя должно выводится 0 1 2. Т.е. не ожидается выполнение FunctionA, и сразу выполняется следующий код. А нужно чтобы ожидалось.

Comment: Не может быть, `FunctionA` у вас выполняется синхронно. Вы уверены, что `Console.Writeln(2);` лежит в вашем примере на правильном месте?

Comment: Вы ничего не путаете? Язык точно C#? прям не поленился прогнал ваш код и он полностью корректно отрабатывает в рамках последовательности вызова (не считая не существующего метода Console.Writeln ) 
Правда возможна следующаяя ситуация: Метод FunctionZ() возвращает управление до того как полностью отработает поток, создаваемый в теле метода, соответственно если метод FunctionZ() вызывается многократно, то действительно можно наблюдать ситуацию, когда будет выведено 0 2 1. но в этом случае вывод 2-ки будет принадлежать потоку который был создан в предыдущий вызов нежели тот, который вывел 0 и 1

Comment: Уверен. Это упрошенный пример. Понятно что в коде не просто вывод в консоль. В функции FunctionA код, который выполняется примерно 3-4 секунды. И происходит так что он ещё не завершился а так скажем 2 уже вывелось в лог.

Comment: Ещё один интересный момент, если взять весь код функции FunctionA и просто впихнуть его на место вызова функции. То код отрабатывает как надо.

Comment: В функции FunctionA точно код выполняется последовательно, без создания новых потоков или асинхронного вызова? Если функция FunctionA  выполняется последовательно, то она просто не может вернуть управление раньше, чем выполнится.

Comment: Alexey огромное спасибо) Не обратил на это внимание. Действительно внутри функции FunctionA создавался новый поток!

Comment: @LorDo может быть тогда стоит обновить код в вопросе? потому что тот, что вы привели, в принципе не может вывести 0 2 1

Answer (score 2):

После вызова `Start()` у вас запускается новый поток, который живет своей жизнью, в нем выполняется `FunctionA`
Чтобы дождаться выполнения этого потока в какой-то точке, нужно вызвать метод `Join`

```
void FunctionZ()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
    {
      /* Какие-то действия */

        FunctionA();

      /* Какие-то действия */

    });

    thread.Start(); //Поток запустился на выполнение

    thread.Join(); //В этой строке ждем окончание его выполнения

}
```

Comment: Немного конкретизировал проблему. Смотрите правку.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать Join. А можно просто отказаться от создания отдельного потока для выполнения операций, которые необходимо дождаться.

```
 void FunctionZ()
    {       
          /* Какие-то действия */

            FunctionA();

          /* Какие-то действия */
    }
```

Если создание отдельного потока использовалось вами для того, чтобы UI не "фризился" то разумнее будет использовать в этом случае асинхронный вызов.

Что применять конкретно в вашем случае зависит от многих нюансов проекта. Решать вам.

Comment: Немного конкретизировал проблему. Смотрите правку